# Angular @angular libraries are getting deleted automatically

Tags: angular, package.json

Everytime whem i run npm install the angular libraries inside the @angular folder are getting deleted automatically except 2 folders (platform-browser & platform-browser-dynamic). Next time i will copy it from different folder and again if i run it will be deleted. I have pasted my package.json below, is there any setting causing this,

```
{
  "name": "expressdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run"
  },
  "author": "Parameswari",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "oracledb": "^1.13.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.2",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not included angular dependencies in your package.json

So add all your angular dependencies in package.jaon under dependencies section the way other two libraries included

```
         dependencies {
             @angular/core: 4.2.5
         }
```